# Array of int pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I came across this question:

> In the declaration below , p is a pointer to an array of 5 int
>   pointers.
>
> int *(*p)[5];
>
> which of the following statements can be used to allocate memory for
>   the first dimension in order to make p an array of 3 arrays of 5
>   pointers to type int ?
>
> A. p = new int [3][5]*;
>
> B. p = new int (*)[3][5];
>
> C. p = new int [3]*[5];
>
> D. p = new int *[3][5];
>
> E. p = new int (* [3] ) [5];

What is the answer ?

I am not sure I understand the question. Normally I would create a pointer to an array of 5 int as such  `int* p[5];` I am curious as to why they did it as `int *(*p)[5];`

Also what does the question want ? Is it asking to initialize (allocate memory) to the first 3 int pointers ?  I would appreciate it if someone could explain this to me

Comment: F. `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3>`

Comment: G. `auto p = std::array<std::array<int*, 5>, 3>{{}};`

Answer (score 1):

F:

```
using IPA5 = int*[5];

IPA5 * p = new IPA5[3];
```

Each element `p[0]`, `p[1]`, `p[2]` is just a plain, typed array of `int*`. There's nothing dynamic going on beyond the initial dynamic allocation, where `3` is allowed to be a dynamic quantity.

Then `p[0][i]` for `i` in `[0, 5)` is an `int *`, which you can use in whatever way you like (which includes making it point to the first element of yet anohter dynamic array).

Answer (score 1):

What you would write as:

```
int* p[5];
```

is a five element array of pointers to `int`.

What this declares:

```
int *(*p)[5];
```

is a pointer to a five element array of pointers to `int`, i.e. a pointer to the type of thing you just wrote.

In other words; you could do:

```
int * a[5];
int * (*p)[5] = &a;
```

You can mentally read this incrementally as follows:

```
(*p)               //  p is a pointer
(*p)[5]            //  p is a pointer to an array of size 5
int * (*p)[5]      //  p is a pointer to an array of size 5 of type pointer to int
```

You need the parentheses around `*p`, because otherwise:

```
int ** p[5];
```

would declare a 5 element array of type `int **`, or pointer to pointer to `int`, which is a different thing entirely.

The question is basically asking you to dynamically allocate memory equivalent to three of what `a` is above, so answer "D" is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

`int* p[5]` has type `array of size 5 of int*`. It decays to `int**`, so `p + 1` will point to the second element of that array.

`int *(*p)[5]` has type `pointer to array of size 5 of int*`. You can think of it as decayed two-dimensional array `int* [][5]`. So `p + 1` will point to the second element of *the first dimension* of that array, that is to the next byte after 5 pointers to int.

Which leads us to the conclusion that the right answer is `D`.

(This is not to mention that other answers just don't compile regardless of type of `p`)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 
D. p = new int *[3][5];
all the others are syntactically wrong

to realize the difference between 
int * p [5]; 
int * (*p) [5];

consider this example
    int *(*p)[5];
    int *pp[5];

    pp[0][0] = new int [5]; //LHS is int , RHS is int* ,, compilation error
    p[0][0] = new int [5]; //this works because p[0][0] is a pointer not an int

try thinking about each dimension as adding you additional *
back to the question 
int *(*p)[5] is giving you 3 * (***p)
so you can assign 
p = int *[3][5]
because it has 3 * as well

Answer (score 0):

- What is the answer ?

D

- Normally I would create a pointer to an array of 5 int as such `int* p[5]`; I am curious as to why they did it as `int *(*p)[5]`;

It is not "normally" because `int* p[5]` is not a pointer to an array of 5 int, it is an array of 5 pointers to int.

- Also what does the question want ? Is it asking to initialize (allocate memory) to the first 3 int pointers ?

It's not clear. There is no way "to make p an array of 3 arrays of 5 pointers to type int", to begin with.