# Why can't I use a for each loop on array of int pointers in C++

Tags: arrays, pointers, c++11

I'm trying to have an array of pointers (`int *a[10]`) and then use a range based for loop (as in the C++11 standard). However, the compiler complains D: - it says "error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘int*’".

My code is basically:

```
main(){
    int *a[10];
    for(int& e : a){}
}
```

I had also tried:
    //...
    for(int* e : a){}

But having neither, inside the loop body, `*e = 1` or `e = 1` works.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028070/array-of-int-pointers) which links me to [this page](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for); by reading that, I think I understand that the container you're trying to iterate over must implement a `begin()` and an `end()` methods. I guess the primitive arrays don't implement these; is that the case? Also, is it the case that `int& a = c;` makes a have the same address as c, for some `int c`?

Is there another alternative?

Comment: Or `for(int *&e : a) {}` if you want to access the pointers themselves.

Comment: Or `for (auto e : a) {}` /  `for (auto &e : a) {}`

Comment: @AlexFarber I thought of that but it doesn't seem to be the behavior I want

Comment: @Quentin I do want to access them, but I don't understand how that works, then, because `for(int *&e : a){*e = 1;}` seems to do nothing, when I print it.

Comment: That's because you didn't initialize your pointers.

Comment: But I'm trying to initialize them in the loop! Is that not allowed?

Comment: @someonewithpc: If you want to initialize them, you must have a reference to the pointer. See Quentin's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*e = 1` suggests that you want to make 10 pointers to 10 integers, each of which has the value 1.

First, you need to have a loop that references all the 10 pointers:

```
int* a[10];
for(int*& e : a) // Reference so you can modify a.
```

Then, you need to create 10 pointers:

```
  e = new int;
```

and those have to be pointers to the value 1 so we complete the statement

```
 *e = 1;
```

or shorter

```
  e = new int (1);
```

When cleaning up, you'd have a similar loop:

```
 for (int& e : a) {
      delete e;
      e = nullptr;
 }
```

Comment: It works if I use `for(int *&e : a)` but not if I do `for(auto e : a)`. Why is that? With the latter I get "173680127\n-1161788088" as the output.

Comment: That's because `auto` is deduced as `int*`. What happens then is that you modify a _copy_ of the pointers in `a`. If you'd use `auto& e: a`, the deduced type of `e` would be `int*& e`. (In other words, the problem is not with `auto` but with leaving off the `&` reference.)

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of `int*`, so of course you can't iterate over it using a variable of type `int`, that isn't the type of object in the array!

The objects in the array are `int*` so that's what your loop variable needs to be.

```
for (int* e : a) ...
```

Or

```
for (int*& e : a) ...
```

Or simply:

```
for (auto& e : a) ...
```

Comment: Right, I thought of the first one, of course, but it doesn't work as I want.